# What is a pTemplate in PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, primeng

I was going through the documentation of PrimeNG 4.3.0 for `p-tree` [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4.3.0/#/tree), and came across this example where they are using a `pTemplate` attribute, but I am unable to understand what it does or how it works.

```
<p-tree [value]="files">
    <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
        <input [(ngModel)]="node.label" type="text" style="width:100%">
    </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

Could someone please explain what the purpose of `pTemplate` is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only purpose of this directive is to hold `ng-template` reference (with some unique key assigned with it). Later inside parent component it is possible to grab the list of `pTemplate` directives:

```
@ContentChildren(PrimeTemplate) templates: QueryList<any>;
```

This list is a pair of `string` key and `TemplateRef` value.

This mechanism allows software developers to use multiple `ng-templates` and inject them to `*ngTemplateOutlet` directives in parent component.

```
<p-tree [value]="files">
    <ng-template let-node  pTemplate="picture">
        <img [attrs.src]="picture.path">
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-node  pTemplate="default">
        <input [(ngModel)]="node.label" type="text" style="width:100%">
    </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the purpose of grabbing the list of pTemplate directives is for, and perhaps limited to, reusing ng-templates?

Comment: How can I see the list of pTemplate directives online? I couldn't find it

Answer (score 11):

pTemplate is a custom-made directive by PrimeNG. Its purpose is to link a template defined by you (the user) to a container defined by the library (PrimeNG).

That enables the user to provide a custom template that is displayed inside a component made by the library.

The above can also be achieved using the [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) directive.

You can create a component which has a **ngTemplateOutlet** on a `<ng-container>` inside it. When using that component you can place `<ng-template>` children between its component selector tags and give them a name. This way you essentially detach UI logic from component logic and achieve greater flexibility.

Here is a great presentation which helped me learn how to ngTemplateOutlet: https://youtu.be/2SnVxPeJdwE